# C# - Elegant alternative to Switch statement using Interface or Dependency Injection in Class Library?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, dependencies, class-library

I have a class library that has a number of associated class libraries tied to it as references, each doing a different data export using unique methods and properties.

To execute one of these exports I am calling a "root" class library from a console app, passing in some information about which export to run.

This root class is doing a simple Switch statement to call one of the exports. And while this code works fine, I don't think it's the most elegant way to do this.

Someone suggested using dependency injection and someone else said to use an interface. After doing some research I couldn't find a good, simple example from which I could learn how to code such implementations.

Below is the Switch statement. Thoughts or ideas?

```
using System;

namespace ABC.Exporter
{
    public class Exporter
    {
        public void Export(string vendorName, string exportName, Client client)
        {
            // which Export are we doing?
            switch (vendorName)
            {
                case "Realogy" when exportName == "DashImportListings":
                    Realogy.Realogy.DashImportListings(client);
                    break;
                case "Zillow" when exportName == "Listings":
                    Zillow.Zillow.Listings(client);
                    break;
                case "Zillow" when exportName == "PastSales":
                    Zillow.Zillow.PastSales(client);
                    break;
                case "Xpressdocs" when exportName == "RecipientListingFeed":
                    Xpressdocs.Xpressdocs.RecipientListingFeed(client);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Export");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, to start with you need a common interface so that the import looks the same for each class.

Comment: Do you control the referenced libraries? If you do, there might be a simple solution for this.

Comment: Yes, I do. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Have all of the different classes you are using (`Realogy.Realogy`, `Zillow.Zillow`) implement an interface with a void method that accept an instance of `Clientt` and instead of passing the vendor name and export name as a string, pass the relevant instance to the method.